# How to remove the screw adapter from glass

Tags: repair, glass

I have this round steel color metal attached to my coffee table glass..I'm trying to use the glass to make coffee table with wood log.Does anyone know to remove the metal screw adapter(I think so it's glued to the glass)

Comment: Probably epoxy adhesive.

Comment: Might be super glue. Acetone will dissolve that.

Comment: A photo would be helpful--advice will be much less likely to cause damage.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a soldering torch and razor blade.

Moving the torch back and forth across the metal adapter quickly so as not to heat it (or the glass) too quickly.   Then try the razor blade between the glass and the metal adapter.  No go?  Apply a little more heat, and try again, until it comes right off.

Comment: This sounds easy enough, but can quickly shatter the table with just a second of careless torch handling.  Even heat over a larger area is key for working with glass like this.  It can be done, but it's not easy.

Comment: If they move it back and forth just a few times, then test with a razor blade scraper, and keep going with that pattern, I think they'd be just fine and it will come off quickly.   Obviously the key is to heat _slowly_.

Comment: Also they should assume the glass is not tempered (because it probably isn't) and whatever they do should make sure they aren't gripping the glass while working with it or have feet or anything important below it, regardless what type of technique they use to remove the adapters.

Comment: A heat gun would give you much more control over the heat distribution than a torch, which is too hot for this purpose. It should loosen up around 500 F. Propane torches burn at over 3,000 F.

Comment: OR when your wife is not looking.. borrow the steam iron...

Answer (score 0):

I bought a £100 glass table just for the glass although it had 6 of these metal adapters glued to it.(thought it'd be worth the risk)
I used a cheap electric soldering iron and ground down a steel bolt so it would replace the tip and could be also screwed into the metal adaptors and rest there while heating up. While it was heating I clamped some mole grips to the metal and applied a constant downward twisting pressure to it until the glue meets its melting / softening point and it comes away. So no heating of the glass and just enough heat to get it off. I wish someone had told me that before I tried it as i was bricking it waiting for the gas to shatter on the first one.